# ValueError: shapes (993,228) and (1,228) not aligned: 228 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, valueerror

I have created a OLS linear regression model in python and when I predict for a particular value I get the error.

My code is below:

```
df=pd.read_csv("smatrix.csv",index_col=0)
import statsmodels.api as sm

x=df.iloc[:,:-1]
y=df.Rating

est = sm.OLS(y.astype(float), x.astype(float))
results=est.fit()

op=list()
for i in df.columns:
    if 'bad' == i:
        op.append(1)
    else:
        op.append(0)
op=op[:-1]
X5=np.array(op).reshape(1,-1)
y1=est.predict(X5)
```

The error that I am getting is

```
ValueError: shapes (993,228) and (1,228) not aligned: 228 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```

The shape of X5 is (1, 228)

The shape of x is (993, 228)

The shape of y is (993,)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`est.predict()` expects the first argument to be params ([more here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.predict)), but you are passing X[5] of shape 1, 128. The error message is thrown when the model tries to multiply X with params(in this case X[5]).

```
X -> (993, 128)
params -> (1, 128)
```

This two matrices(X, params) cannot be multiplied because the columns of X(128) is not aligned with rows of params(1).

#### Solution

Use the parameters learned with fit method.

```
y1=est.predict(results.params, X5)
```

Comment: Hey
I had been struggling with this error for so many hours. This worked like a charm. Thank you so much for saving the day :)