# Statsmodels OLS "Shapes not aligned" Error (Using Built-In Dataset)

Tags: python, statsmodels, least-squares

I'm trying to practice basic modeling in Python. I am trying to create an OLS model using the OLS function in the statsmodels library, and I'm using a built-in dataset from the statsmodels library as well. Everything runs fine when splitting the dataset into training and testing data, training the model, etc until I try to use the model to make predictions from the testing data. My code is below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = datasets.anes96.load_pandas().data
data.head()

train, test = train_test_split(data, test_size=0.2)

x_vars = ['age', 'educ', 'selfLR']
y_var = 'PID'

train_x = train[x_vars]
train_x = sm.add_constant(train_x)
train_y = train[y_var]

model = sm.OLS(train_y, train_x)
results = model.fit()
#print(results.summary())

test_x = test[x_vars]
test_x = sm.add_constant(test_x)

predictions = model.predict(test_x)
```

And I am getting this error:
ValueError: shapes (755,4) and (189,4) not aligned: 4 (dim 1) != 189 (dim 0)

Any help or tips with modelling, maybe some guides with how to work with these datasets, would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: shapes (993,228) and (1,228) not aligned: 228 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003129/valueerror-shapes-993-228-and-1-228-not-aligned-228-dim-1-1-dim-0)

Answer (score 0):

AlexK added a link to a post that helped. Essentially all I added to the predictions = model.predict(test_x) line was a parameter that specified what parameters to use based on the results from the model.fit() line. In other words, the last line now looks like this:

```
predictions = model.predict(results.params, test_x)
```

Link to post that helped: [ValueError: shapes (993,228) and (1,228) not aligned: 228 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54003129/valueerror-shapes-993-228-and-1-228-not-aligned-228-dim-1-1-dim-0)